# migrating SQL Server 2005 instance with Biztalk databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, migration, biztalk

We're trying to migrate a SQL Server 2005 instance. It has a lot of databases including those used by Biztalk Server 2006, Logins and Groups. The strategy has been to backup and restore databases and use SQL scripts to create Logins and Groups (with Biztalk, local user groups control access to databases).

The problem is that though Groups and Logins get created fine, the Groups don't seem to have access to the databases (though Logins do). One possible cause for this is the SIDs being different for the newly created Groups. So:

- Is there a standard/better way to migrate a SQL Server instance with databases and groups controlling access to them?
- Is there a better way to migrate Biztalk server databases? Of course we could just reconfigure Biztalk but we have a lot of SQL Server instances to migrate.

Comment: What resolved the problem for us was altering group permissions using alter user query like so:

USE BizTalkDTADb
ALTER USER [SQLSERVER01\BizTalk Application Users] WITH LOGIN = [SQLSERVER01\BizTalk Application Users].

To sum up, we did the following:
- Backed up and restored databases
- Created sql server logins/groups using sql queries [refer http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992]
- Altered users of databases to associate them to the newly created logins/groups.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember moving BizTalk databases is not easy task. [Here is the documentation for BizTalk 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559835%28v=BTS.70%29.aspx) but after skimming the content it looks similar like the process for 2006 described for example in [Professional BizTalk Server 2006](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470046422).

I'm not sure what you mean by groups but you most probably mean sql logins based on windows groups. Check this [How to article about transferring logins](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992).

Comment: Thanks Ladislav.Yes i was referring to sql logins based on Windows groups.